# How to repair MongoDb when someone deleted one database directory from the db directory?

Tags: mongodb

One guy deleted one Database directory from the dbpath of MongoDb as we configured --directoryperdb.
Is there any option to ignore that database and I can start the server. Currently mongod --repair giving

2020-04-22T15:19:56.118+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (2) [1587568796:118648][22758:0x7fd9688ad580], file:Test/collection-556-3480094503407958
80.wt, WT_SESSION.salvage: /home/dbdir/db/Test/collection-556-348009450340795880.wt: handle-open: open: No such file or directory
2020-04-22T15:19:56.121+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Invariant failure rs.get() src/mongo/db/catalog/database.cpp 195

And when trying to start the server It is giving segmentation fault. Is there any way I can fix the database.

Answer (score 0):

`Test` is the database that was deleted?

After making a backup, grep the remaining tree for other files that reference it and try to delete those as well.

Comment: For example, I kept Test, The database is created with --directoryperdb, and the whole directory is deleted and rest of the files are .wt files.
Is there any option to repair MongoDb skipping that database?

Comment: You could try removing files that reference the deleted database.